# Hide and show text on button click in asp.net core

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, web-applications

I'm creating a web app with an API and wrote some kind of help page with HTML.
For the sake of clarity, I want to hide and show some of the text on button click.

I already got the HTML code for that.

```
<li> GET https://someurl.com/api/getallInformation - some text about data</li>
<div>
    <button onclick="help()">Show Text</button>
</div>
<div id="Text">
    <li>Text that should be shown and hidden on Button click </li>
</div>
```

But I do not know ho to write the **help()-function**, that makes the button work. I'm writing the app in **ASP.NET Core**.
I know there are many examples, but none of those I found seem to fit my problem.
Any idea how to do it ? [Thats what it looks like now. The button just does not work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWDWT.png)

Comment: `document.getElementById("element").addEventListener('click', function () {
        location.href = '@Url.Action("Index","Home")';
    });` In the Url.Action you can specify the Controller name and the Action name. When you click on the Button, it is redirected to the “Index” method in the “Home” controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function help() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Text");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="help()">Help</button>

<div id="Text">
<li>Text that should be shown and hidden on Button click </li>
</div>
```